# Application.ontime code isn't running

Tags: vba, excel

I've done a fair bit of research on here to try and get this code to run, but I'm still having issues.

I am trying to run a macro at a set time. In fact it is a number of macros as different times. This macro then copies a block of cells, into a different area on the sheet.

I will not be able to use windows scheduler so I'm trying to do it this way. I gather without scheduler I will have to run the macro from a button. Therefore, my first sub is this (note button is on a separate sheet to the data)

```
Sub Call_save()

    Call Sheets("Dashboard").8amsave

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:10:00"), "Call_8amsave"

    Call 9amsave

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:10:00"), "Call_9amsave"

    Call 10amsave

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "Call_10amsave"

End Sub
```

This button is designed to then run the subs at the predetermined time. The subs it calls are these:

```
Sub 8amsave()
Dim current_data As Variant

    current_data = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S6:V22").Value
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B33:E49").Value = current_data


End Sub

Sub 9amsave()
Dim current_data As Variant

    current_data = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S6:V22").Value
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B54:E70").Value = current_data


End Sub

Sub 10amsave()
Dim current_data As Variant

    current_data = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S6:V22").Value
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B75:E91").Value = current_data


End Sub
```

Now, when I run the initial button it runs all the subs at once and copies the sells into the correct places, straight away. This isnt really an issue for me. However, at the predetermined time I get an error saying unable to run the macro... can't find it or sheet unable to run macros... or something of that ilk.

Is there anything blindingly obvious that i am missing? I have kind of been working this out as I go along so my VBA knowledge is fairly limited. A point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You can't start a procedure name with a numeric.

Comment: Your `OnTime` statements also appear to be referencing procedure names which don't exist, i.e., `Call_8amSave` as opposed to `8amsave`.  Rename your procedures so that they match the calls in the `OnTime` statement, it should work.  E.g., `Sub Call_8amSave`, etc.

Comment: `Call` statement is completely unnecessary - if you want to execute `MyProcedure`, just say `MyProcedure`, that's a procedure call. `Call` statement is a relic from old, old versions of the language, that remained there for backward compatibility... along with `Let` keyword for value assignments and `Rem` keyword for... comments.

Comment: Thanks David. Apologies, my code does have letters before the numbers, I just removed them to shorten the code of above. I've also amended my reference. I'm still getting the same error. " Cant run macro {file location} The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled". Any ideas?

Comment: Hadn't seen the answers and comments. Ignore my last comment. I'll give the solution a whirl and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnTime` statements also appear to be referencing procedure names which don't exist, i.e., `Call_8amSave` as opposed to `8amsave`.  Note also that procedure names cannot begin with numeric (e.g., `8amsave`) and this code should not even compile, let alone execute.

Rename your procedures so that they match the calls in the `OnTime` statement, and are legally permissible procedure names, like: `Sub Call_8amSave`, etc.

Also, the `OnTime` property can only have one procedure at a time, so you can't set 3 future times, you have to set them sequentially. So, set the `OnTime` for the 9am save during the 8am procedure, etc.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Call_save()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:10:00"), "Call_8amsave"

End Sub
Sub Call_8amsave()

    With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        .Range("B33:E49").Value = .Range("S6:V22").Value
    End With

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:10:00"), "Call_9amsave"
End Sub

Sub Call_9amsave()

    With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        .Range("B54:E70").Value = .Range("S6:V22").Value
    End With

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "Call_10amsave"
End Sub

Sub Call_10amsave()

    With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        .Range("B75:E91").Value = .Range("S6:V22").Value
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help David. I have included this code, but I'm still getting the error. It seems its unable to find "Sub Call_8amsave()"

Comment: Cannot run the macro "Z:\Test sheet new.xlsm'!Call_8amsave'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: You need to include the module name like `z:\my workbook.xlsm!Module_Name.Procedure_Name`

Comment: I'm a little lost. Where do I need to include the module name in your above code?. I've had a look on google, but I'm not getting anywhere. If my workbook is called "test sheet" for example. I would use...."z:\test sheet.xlsm!Dashboard.Call_9amsave" ?

Comment: You need to include the module name like `z:\my workbook.xlsm!**Module_Name.**Procedure_Name` Is your module called `Dashboard`?

Comment: So the macros are all in the same file. I have input the code you gave above into Sheet1(core). This is the sheet I have the button to set the code running, I then set the button. The actual date that i'm copying is in Sheet2(dashboard) i.e VBA project > Microsoft excel objects.

Comment: the module is called `Sheet2`. The worksheet is called "Dashboard", but the module name is still the worksheet's codename.

Comment: Or, simply put the code in a *standard* module and you don't need to qualify it with the sheet name or the filename. You can just do `Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:10:00"), "Call_8amsave"`.

Comment: Ahh problem solved. I moved it to a standard module. You have been a great help. Very much appreciated.